# How to use global function to pick up every iteration javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Quite new to this, hopefully there is a simple explanation to my issue:

Depending on which value entered in the input areas, background color changes, console log (and output in span) a "score" according to colored cell.
Now, I want each score to be saved in variables to be used for a sum up in the end for both rows.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```js
function update_scores(element, val)
{
 console.log(val);
 if (val == "")
  console.log("empty");
 var scores = {};
 var data_element = $(element).closest('.my-data');

 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  var index_element = "scores-e" + i;
  var data = data_element.data(index_element);

  if (data)
  {
   scores[i] = data;
  }
 }

 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {
  var cell = data_element.find(".e" + i).parent();
  var vitals = scores[i];
  if (vitals)
  {
   if (val != "" && (val >= vitals["min"] && val <= vitals["max"]))
   {
    cell.css("background-color", vitals["background-color"]);
    cell.css("font-weight", "bold");
    tews_score = vitals["param-score"];
    console.log("total score:", tews_score);
    $("#total_score").text(tews_score);
   }
   else
   {
    cell.css("background-color", "white");
    cell.css("font-weight", "normal");
   }
  }
 }
}

 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#af").keyup(function() {
   update_scores(this, $(this).val());
  });
  
  $("#npb").keyup(function() {
   update_scores(this, $(this).val());
  });
 });
```

```css
table, table td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>VP</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="my-data"
  data-scores-e0='{"min": 0, "max": 8, "background-color": "orange", "param-score": "2"}'
  data-scores-e1='{"min": 9, "max": 14, "background-color": "green", "param-score": "1"}'
  data-scores-e2='{"min": 15, "max": 20, "background-color": "yellow", "param-score": "0"}'
  data-scores-e3='{"min": 21, "max": 29, "background-color": "orange", "param-score": "1"}'
  data-scores-e4='{"min": 30, "max": 100, "background-color": "red", "param-score": "2"}'
 >
  <td>
   <p><strong>B</strong></p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <strong>Breathing/min:</strong>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p><input id="af" type="number" size="1" maxlength="2"></p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e0">≤8</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e1">9-14</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e2">15-20</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e3">21-29</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e4">≥30</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td>VP</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>

 <tr class="my-data"
  data-scores-e0='{"min": 0, "max": 70, "background-color": "orange", "param-score": "2"}'
  data-scores-e1='{"min": 71, "max": 89, "background-color": "yellow", "param-score": "1"}'
  data-scores-e2='{"min": 90, "max": 140, "background-color": "green", "param-score": "0"}'
  data-scores-e3='{"min": 141, "max": 199, "background-color": "yellow", "param-score": "1"}'
  data-scores-e4='{"min": 200, "max": 500, "background-color": "orange", "param-score": "2"}'
 >
  <td>
   <p><strong>C</strong></p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <strong>NBP:</strong>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p><input id="npb" type="number" size="1" maxlength="3"></p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e0">≤70</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e1">71-89</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e2">90-140</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e3">141-199</p>
  </td>
  <td>
   <p class="e4">≥200</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<div>Total score: <span id="total_score"></div>
</html>
```

Comment: The snippet editor has three separate parts to add your code: Markup/HTML, JavaScript, CSS. It's not "choose one of them and throw all of your code in it" -> [How do I create a runnable snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Well, depends on how you've written the code?
In this case, the purpose is to use one file only, so I wanted to show how it's written as is. No problem to separate in snippet editor if there is a directive how to use it(?), didn't just think it mattered...

Comment: A snippet is meant to be used with runnable code which shows the actual problem you have. If it is not meant to be executed by us or it is not runnable then do not use a snippet, instead use a regular code block `{}` (or indent four spaces by hand)